# R: list with 613607 elements, each containing 2...? and want to convert "?" into a data frame

Tags: r, list

With apologies, this is a question borne of ignorance about lists.  I used "stringr" to parse a text variable from a web log file data frame, with the ultimate goal of understanding the relative frequency of different file types served up on a website.  The data came out in the following list format (after being parsed on a period):

```
List of 613607
 $ : chr [1:2] "/btauxdir/getsimpleload" "cfm"
 $ : chr [1:2] "/btauxdir/getsimpleload" "cfm"
 $ : chr [1:2] "/btauxdir/getsimpleload" "cfm"
 $ : chr [1:2] "/btauxdir/getsimpleload" "cfm"
 $ : chr [1:2] "/btauxdir/getsimpleload" "cfm"
 $ : chr [1:2] "/btauxdir/getsimpleload" "cfm"
 $ : chr [1:2] "/btauxdir/getsimpleload" "cfm"
 $ : chr [1:2] "/btauxdir/getsimpleload" "cfm"
 $ : chr [1:2] "/index" "cfm"
 $ : chr [1:2] "/monitor/serverstatus" "cfm"
```

The second...thing? column? element? sub-list? (I don't even know what to call it)...all of which have a value "cfm" in this example, could be a variety of different 2 and 3 character file extensions (.tz, .jpg, etc.).

I want to convert the second thing of the list into a column of data (ultimately to put back into my original data frame and run distribution graphs on the file types).

I've spent about 90 minutes on this with a variety of solutions from more than a few Springer and O'Reilly books.  Ultimately, I think I just don't understand R lists (I'm not a programmer, so the "It's just like X in programming language Y doesn't help me).

The entire process of exporting the variable to Excel, parsing it into 2 columns, and reimporting into R and binding to the original dataframe took me less than two minutes (sigh).  But that's not why I'm here, right? I'm here to learn and hope you all will be able to help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `do.call(rbind, list)`

Comment: and `sapply(list, "[[", 2)`

Comment: Thank you, rawr and Jake Burkhead (and for being gentle with a newbie).  "do.call(rbind, list" appears to have worked.  For some reason, "sapply..." generated the following error message:  Error in FUN(X[[6724L]], ...) : subscript out of bounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argh: I don't know where I found the following code - may have been here or not (searched but couldn't find it).  With thanks to all who contributed, this answered my question:

```
myParsedData <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', 
                                   strsplit(as.character(myData$myVariable), 
                                            '.', fixed=TRUE)))
```

So, this takes the variable I wanted to parse (`myVariable`), splits it on a period, then returns it as a `data.frame` with 2 variables, `X1` (the left-hand side of my parse) and `X2` (the right-hand side).

Then, I `cbind`'ed `X2` to my original `myData`.

Thank you to the anonymous donor!

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, you have a list of character vectors of length 2. In code, this would be

```
a <- c("element11", "element12")
b <- c("element21", "element22")
c <- c("element31", "element32")
abc <- list(a, b, c)
str(abc)

List of 3
 $ : chr [1:2] "element11" "element12"
 $ : chr [1:2] "element21" "element22"
 $ : chr [1:2] "element31" "element32"
```

You can extract individual elements from each list element (a, b or c) using `lapply` or `sapply` as mentioned by @Jake Burkhead.

For pedagogical reasons, I'm including his comment here:

```
sapply(abc, "[[", 2)
[1] "element12" "element22" "element32"
```

You are asking sapply (or lapply) to perform a function "[[" on a list. The `2` there is passed on as a `...` argument, and is used as an index. If you do it by hand, this would be equivalent to

```
> c(abc[[1]][2], abc[[2]][2], abc[[3]][2])
[1] "element12" "element22" "element32"
```

You can think of lapply or sapply as a hidden loop that loops through a dimension of your data applying a specified function.

Comment: Thanks, Roman.  Very helpful explanation and gave me a good sense of how lists are organized.  Per the above, the "sapply..." didn't work :-(

Comment: Hi, Roman - When it hit a blank (which, in fairness, I didn't specify), it failed.

Comment: Exclude blank entries or instead of `"[["` define a function, that will subset the data or do something else if the entry happens to be blank, @user2621147.